# Checking for NaNs in many columns in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I want to add a binary column to my dataframe based on whether given columns contain NaN or not.

I have tried to do it with the below code.

```
import pandas as pd

dat = pd.DataFrame({'A': [12,34,56,78, 23,None, None], 'B': [90,80,70,23,None, 78, None], 'C': [90,80,70,23,None, 78, None], 'D': [12,34,56,78, 23,None, None]})
dat['A1'] = dat['A'].isnull()
dat['B1'] = dat['B'].isnull()
dat['C1'] = dat['C'].isnull()
dat['ismissing'] = 1 if dat['A1'] == True and dat['B1'] == True and dat['C1'] == True else 0
dat
```

but I got a ValueError at the line before last.

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Sample input:

```
A     B     C     D
10   NaN    40    NaN
NaN  NaN    80    90
20    45    NaN   89
NaN  NaN    NaN   46
```

Expected output:

```
A     B     C     D     E
10   NaN    40    NaN   0
NaN  NaN    80    90    0
20    45    NaN   89    0
NaN  NaN    NaN   46    1
```

I want to check NaNs only for A, B, C columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to check whether a row with columns(`A,B,C`) has all `nan` or not.

You can do this using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [1711]: import numpy as np

In [1710]: dat['E'] = np.where(dat[['A','B','C']].isnull().all(1), 1, 0)    
In [1711]: dat
Out[1711]: 
      A     B     C     D  E
0  12.0  90.0  90.0  12.0  0
1  34.0  80.0  80.0  34.0  0
2  56.0  70.0  70.0  56.0  0
3  78.0  23.0  23.0  78.0  0
4  23.0   NaN   NaN  23.0  0
5   NaN  78.0  78.0   NaN  0
6   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN  1
```

Performance comparison:

Quang Hoang's answer:

```
In [1720]: %timeit df['ismissing'] = df[['A','B','C']].isna().all(axis=1)
989 µs ± 70 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

YOBEN_S's answer:

```
In [1719]: %timeit df['New']=~df.index.isin(df.drop('D',1).dropna(thresh=1).index)
2.05 ms ± 113 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

anky's answer:

```
In [1724]: %timeit df['all_nan'] = df[['A','B','C']].count(axis=1).eq(0).view('i1')
1.48 ms ± 117 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

My answer:

```
In [1723]: %timeit dat['E'] = np.where(dat[['A','B','C']].isnull().all(1), 1, 0)
914 µs ± 18.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

As you can see, my answer with `np.where` is the fastest.

Comment: Thanks @anky. I tried to go for an optimized solution.

Comment: @anky I further checked, actually `isna()` and `isnull()` don't show much difference in performance. The major shift is due to `np.where`.

Answer (score 3):

Note that `and` expect a single boolean variable, which `pd.Series` is not. That's why python complains that it doesn't know how to convert  a `pd.Series` to a boolean.

Instead, you can (and should) do:

```
df['ismissing'] = df[['A','B','C']].isna().all(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 2):

I created a column with true and false, then applied one if it is true and 0 if it is false

```
dat['ismissing'] = dat.isnull().all(axis=1)
dat['ismissing'] = dat['ismissing'].apply(lambda x: 1 if x else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us try something new

```
df['New']=~df.index.isin(df.drop('D',1).dropna(thresh=1).index)
df
      A     B     C     D    New
0  10.0   NaN  40.0   NaN  False
1   NaN   NaN  80.0  90.0  False
2  20.0  45.0   NaN  89.0  False
3   NaN   NaN   NaN  46.0   True
```